# jQuery src selector Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm doing a poker game.
I have an issue about a jQuery selector.

```
$('[src$='+a+']').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
```

It tells me *Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [src$=♠6.jpg]*

Here is the code :

```
function CartesJoueur(){
var random1 = " "; // 1ere carte : variable aléatoire sur une même famille (famille ♦ par exemple)
var random2 = " "; // 2eme carte : variable aléatoire sur les symboles (♦ ♣ ♥ ♠)
var random3 = " "; // 1ere carte : variable aléatoire sur une même famille (famille ♦ par exemple)
var random4 = " "; // 2eme carte : variable aléatoire sur les symboles (♦ ♣ ♥ ♠)

random1 = getRandomInt(2, 14); //nombre aléatoire entre 2 et 14
random2 = getRandomInt(2, 14); //nombre aléatoire entre 2 et 14
random3 = getRandomInt(1, 4); //nombre aléatoire entre 1 et 4
random4 = getRandomInt(1, 4); //nombre aléatoire entre 1 et 4

if(random3 === 1)
    var string1 = "images/♠" + random1 + ".jpg";
else if(random3 === 2)
    var string1 = "images/♣" + random1 + ".jpg";
else if(random3 === 3)
    var string1 = "images/♦" + random1 + ".jpg";
else if(random3 === 4)
    var string1 = "images/♥" + random1 + ".jpg";

if(random4 === 1)
    var string2 = "images/♠" + random2 + ".jpg";
else if(random4 === 2)
    var string2 = "images/♣" + random2 + ".jpg";
else if(random4 === 3)
    var string2 = "images/♦" + random2 + ".jpg";
else if(random4 === 4)
    var string2 = "images/♥" + random2 + ".jpg";

//permet d'éviter d'avoir deux fois la même image
if(random3 === random4 && random1 === random2)
{
    random2 = getRandomInt(2, 14);
    random4 = getRandomInt(1, 4);
}

//affichage des deux images 
$('#6row').after('<img src=' + string1 + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
$('#6row').after('<img src=' + string2 + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
// console.log("hey " + random1 + " " + random3); // DEBUG

a =string1.substring(7);
console.log(a);

$('[src$='+a+']').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');

}
```

Could you tell me what i must modify in the selector ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but it might be because you have ♦ ♣ ♥ ♠ in the filename. Doubtful, but it would be better to name those file diamond, hearts, clubs, and spades.

Comment: you have to escape special characters in jQuery selectors...see selector docs

Comment: ♦ ♣ ♠ ♥ do not create problems, indeed if i try $('[src$="2♣.jpg"]').replaceWith(....); it works.

Comment: So...does the special character come before or after the number in the filenames?

Comment: Maybe too simple, but have you tried adding quotes?  Following from your example in the comments, `$('[src$="'+a+'"]')` with quotes around the inserted string.

Comment: if it is not in game context , i will answer your question . Unf.!

Comment: mr rogers    $('[src$="'+a+'"]')    works !!!!!  Thank you everybody for the help.

Comment: Now I have to figure out how to apply the change only for <p id="1row"></p>, <p id="2row"></p> , <p id="3row"></p> , <p id="4row"></p>  (each cards row). I'll try the *:lt()* selector.

Answer (score 0):

[mr rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657639/mr-rogers) solves OP's problem:

> Maybe too simple, but have you tried adding quotes? Following from your example in the comments, `$('[src$="'+a+'"]')` with quotes around the inserted string. –  mr rogers Dec 30 '14 at 3:50